# JMS synchronous communication

Tags: java, jms

In the following [this](http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/pointToPoint-1.htm), there is code for a basic JMS synchronous receiver.

The question I have is this: When a message is delivered to the queue, because it is synchronous, it will automatically be available via the `receiver.receive` method. Is this correct?

If this is so, then after `msg1` arrives on queue, while we are still processing `receiver.receive()`. what happens if `msg2` arrives on queue.

since the call `receiver.receive()` has not returned, will it be able to still receive the message # 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg2` will remain on the queue until another consumer calls `receive()`.